# How to import CSV as hashtable and append duplicated values?

Tags: powershell, csv

Let's say I have the following CSV file:

```
Employee,Software,Manager
Alice,Lorem Ipsum,Bob
Alice,Dolor,Bob
Alice,Sit Amet,Bob
Charlie,Lorem Ipsum,
Charlie,Dolor,
David,Dolor,Stephen
```

I want to have a hashtable like this:

```
@{
    "Alice" = @{
        "Software" = @("Lorem Ipsum", "Dolor", "Sit Amet");
        "Manager" = "Bob"
    }
};
"Charlie" = @{
    "Software" = @("Lorem Ipsum", "Dolor");
    "Manager" =
}
};
"David" = @{
    "Software" = @("Dolor");
    "Manager" = "Stephen"
}
};
```

How is that possible in PowerShell? It would be a hashtable containing another hashtable and inside that inner hashtable I would have an array.

Comment: There are some spurious closing brackets in your hashtable structure, I suppose? How do you want to handle employees with manager mismatches (different/missing managers for the same employee, be it accidentally or on purpose)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over each employee, create an inner hashtable with the software and manager. Add it to the outer hashtable.

```
$csv =  Import-CSV C:\temp\test.csv
$Employees = $csv.Employee | Select-Object -Unique
$EmployeesHT = @{}
foreach ($Employee in $Employees) {
    $EmployeeDetails = $csv | Where-Object {$_.Employee -eq $Employee}
    $EmployeeHT = @{
        'Software' = $EmployeeDetails.Software
        'Manager' = $EmployeeDetails.Manager | Sort-Object -Unique
    }
    $EmployeesHT.Add($Employee, $EmployeeHT)
}
```

Comment: Clean and elegant way of dealing with the task. I only changed the line `'Software' = $EmployeeDetails.Software` to `'Software' = $EmployeeDetails.Software | Sort-Object -Unique` to avoid possible dups.

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop over the content of the csv building a complex hash:

```
$arr = Import-Csv file.csv
$dict = @{}
foreach ($emp in $arr) {
    $name = $emp.Employee
    if ($dict.Contains($name)) {
        $dict[$name]["Software"].add($emp.Software)
        if ($emp.Manager -ne "") {
            $dict[$name]["Manager"] = $emp.Manager
        }
    }
    else {
        $dict[$name] = @{"Software"= New-Object System.collections.arraylist;
                          "Manager"= $emp.Manager }
        $dict[$name]["Software"].add($emp.Software)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$csv = ConvertFrom-CSV -Input @"
Employee,Software,Manager
Alice,Lorem Ipsum,Bob
Alice,Dolor,Bob
Alice,Sit Amet,Bob
Charlie,Lorem Ipsum,
Charlie,Dolor,
David,Dolor,Stephen
"@
```

Building your `Employees` hashtable:

```
$Employees = @{}
$csv | ForEach {$Employees[$_.Employee] = @{Software = $Employees[$_.Employee].Software, $_.Software | Where {$_}; Manager = $_.Manager}}
```

Result:

```
PS C:\> $Employees | ConvertTo-JSON
{
    "Alice":  {
                  "Manager":  "Bob",
                  "Software":  [
                                   {
                                       "value":  "Lorem Ipsum Dolor",
                                       "Count":  2
                                   },
                                   "Sit Amet"
                               ]
              },
    "Charlie":  {
                    "Manager":  "",
                    "Software":  [
                                     "Lorem Ipsum",
                                     "Dolor"
                                 ]
                },
    "David":  {
                  "Manager":  "Stephen",
                  "Software":  "Dolor"
              }
}
```

*Note:* You might consider to tread the `Manager` property similar to the `software` property (meaning: `Manager = $Employees[$_.Employee].Manager, $_.Manager | Where {$_}`) so that employees could theoretical have multiple managers but more important that you can't overrule a manager defined manager in an earlier record with an empty value in an following record.